# LLDB: What's the class of an object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, lldb

Is there a way to find out the class of an object in LLDB, while the object itself is represented by an `id`. Something like `isKindOfClass`, that returns what class it actually is and not just `id`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems `po [myObject class]` works. If anyone has a better solution please post it.

Comment: This is the way to do it, in the debugger or anywhere else. The `id` is the type the compiler uses for the _variable_. The object itself, at the other end of the variable, knows what class it is.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift, `po type(of:myObject)` works.